# Intuition for Essential Embedding

Tags: category-theory, intuition

To begin, let me first state some definitions from [Joy of Cats](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf),

> **Definition 1.** Let $(\mathbf{A},U)$ be a concrete category over $\mathbf{X}$ (i.e, where $\mathbf{A}$ is a category and $U:\mathbf{A}\to\mathbf{X}$ is a faithful functor).
>
> - An $\mathbf{A}$-morphism $A\overset{f}{\to} B$ is called **initial** provided that for any $\mathbf{A}$-object $C$ and for the $\mathbf{X}$-morphism $U(C)\overset{g}{\to} U(A)$ there exists a unique $\mathbf{A}$-morphism $C\overset{g^\ast}{\to} A$ such that $U(g^\ast)=g$ whenever for the $\mathbf{X}$-morphism $U(C)
>   \overset{U(f)\circ g}{\longrightarrow} U(B)$ there exists a unique $\mathbf{A}$-morphism $C\overset{h^\ast}{\to} B$ such that $U(h^\ast)=U(f)\circ g$.
> - An initial morphism $A\overset{f}{\to} B$ for which $U(f)$ is a monomorphism is called an **embedding**.
>
> **Definition 2.** Let $(\mathbf{A},U)$ over $\mathbf{X}$ be a concrete category and $C$ be an $\mathbf{A}$-object. Then $C$ will be said to be *injective* provided that for any embedding
>   $A\overset{m}{\longrightarrow} B$ and any $\mathbf{A}$-morphism $A\overset{f}{\longrightarrow}C$ there exists an $\mathbf{A}$-morphism $B\overset{g}{\longrightarrow} C$ such that $f=g\circ m$.
>
> **Definition 3.** Let $(\mathbf{A},U)$ over $\mathbf{X}$ be a concrete category and $A,B$ be two $\mathbf{A}$-objects. An embedding $A\overset{m}{\longrightarrow}B$ is said to be *essential* if for any $\mathbf{A}$-object $C$ and any $\mathbf{A}$-morphism $B\overset{f}{\longrightarrow}C$ whenever $f\circ m$ is an embedding, so is $f$.

**My Question**

I am trying to understand the reason behind calling these embeddings as stated in Def. 3 "essential". I have already tried to discuss this question [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52960737#52960737) and although the term "essential submodule" has been beautifully motivated by Denis Nardin (as you can see [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52960893#52960893)), I couldn't find motivation the term "essential embedding" in a similar way. So my question is,

> Why are these embeddings as elaborated in Def. 3 called **essential** embeddings?

Comment: Perhaps it wasn't clear from the discussion in the chatroom, but an essential submodule $B$ of $A$ is an example of an essential embedding $B\to A$. If that was clear, then I'm not sure what exactly still needs elucidation.

Comment: @KevinCarlson: I have two questions. (1) Do you mean to say that for each essential embedding you get a unique essential submodule and vice versa? Also by the statement "an essential submodule $B$ of $A$ is an example of an essential embedding $B\to A$" you really meant that "an essential submodule $B$ of $A$ is an example of an essential embedding $B\to A$ **modulo the (canonical?) bijection**", am I right?

Comment: (2) Does this mean that the term "essential embedding" is not motivated by any concrete categorical property but rather was just chosen the name more or less arbitrarily since (probably) it was obtained by generalizing the concept of "essential embedding"? If not then what intuitively distinguishes an essential embedding from an ordinary embedding?